# Access SQLite3 database that is located up one directory from application folders

Tags: python, sqlite, package, flask

I have a directory structure for my flask application as follows.  I have a main application folder with two separate folders underneath it.  One is for some db jobs that I will schedule the other is for the flask application.  Any ideas on what I need to do to be able to access the db from each of the application folders?

```
--MainApp
----__init__.py
----database.db
------FlaskWebApp
--------__init__.py
--------runserver.py
------DBJobs
--------__init__.py
--------dbJobsMain.py
```

What I want to be able to do is access the database.db file from runserver.py or dbJobsMain.py.  Any ideas on what I have to do to make that happen? Or are there better ways to structure this application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `configuration.py` module to your `MainApp` package with:

```
import os.path

package_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
database_path = os.path.join(package_dir, 'database.db')
```

then wherever you need to have access to the database path, use `from MainApp import configuration`, after which you can access `configuration.database_path` to get that path.